# PHP: How to make a wrapper for collection, which will return next element of collection every time I call it

Tags: php, algorithm, collections

I have a collection of objects. Every time when I get an element of this collection, I want to be sure that I get next element in this collections, when I get to the end of collection I just simply start to iterate it from very beginning.

For instance:

```
    $listOfObjects = new WrappedCollection(array('Apple','Banana','Pikachu'));
    $listOfObjects.getElement(); //I get Apple
    $listOfObjects.getElement(); //I get Banana
    $listOfObjects.getElement(); //I get Pikachu
    $listOfObjects.getElement(); //I get Apple
```

I already implemented this with SplDoublyLinkedList, but everytime when I need to loop this list, I need to save the position of iterator, I am sure that there is a way to implement this more beautiful.

```
    $this->listOfRunningCampaigns = new \SplDoublyLinkedList();

    // Getting element of collection
    public function getNextRunningCampaign(): Campaign
    {
        $this->listOfRunningCampaigns->next();
        if ($this->listOfRunningCampaigns->current() !== null)
        {
            return $this->listOfRunningCampaigns->current();
        }

        $this->listOfRunningCampaigns->rewind();

        return $this->listOfRunningCampaigns->current();
    }
```

Here is example of what I have to do when I loop through collection:

```
    // Saving current iterator position
    $currentIteratorPosition = $this->listOfRunningCampaigns->key();

    for ($this->listOfRunningCampaigns->rewind(); $this->listOfRunningCampaigns->valid(); $this->listOfRunningCampaigns->next())
    {
        //... some action
    }

    $this->moveRunningCampaignsListIterator($currentIteratorPosition);

    // Function that moves iterator
    private function moveRunningCampaignsListIterator($index): void
    {
        for ($this->listOfRunningCampaigns->rewind(); $this->listOfRunningCampaigns->valid(); $this->listOfRunningCampaigns->next())
        {
            if ($this->listOfRunningCampaigns->key() === $index)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

In my opinion the way I implemented this looks really bad, In near future I am about to make a lot of different actions with the elements of this collection and taking care of iterator every time is not the way I want to see this working. Can you please suggest some ways of implementing this?

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't just use [`next()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.next.php)? This built-in function will do the rest with the array pointer for you.

In case you want to develop an array wrapper, I think you should take a look at [`Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection`](https://github.com/doctrine/collections/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/Common/Collections/ArrayCollection.php), or use it directly, they did a great job and it also is available via Composer

Comment: Erm, what made you think that I don't use `next()` ? :) Every time you loop the collection you have to save current pointer position, so just using `next()` is not the answer for this question.

ArrayCollection is a good thing, I'll take a closer look at it.